# How can an object be destructed more times than it has been constructed?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a class whose constructor is only called once, but its destructor is called three times.

```
void test_body()
{
    std::cout << "----- Test Body -----" << "\n";

    System system1;

    Body body1({1,1,1}, {2,2,2}, 1, system1);

    system1.add_body(body1);

    std::cout << system1.get_bodies()[0].get_pos() << "\n";
}
```

body.hpp:

```
class Body {

private:
    Vec3D pos_;
    Vec3D vel_;
    double mass_{ 1 };
    System* system_{ nullptr };

public:

    /*#### Constructors ####*/

    Body() noexcept = default;

    Body(Vec3D pos, Vec3D vel, double mass, System& system):
    pos_(pos), vel_(vel), system_{&system}
    {
        if (mass <= 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("Mass cannot be negative.");
        mass_ = mass;

        std::cout << "Constructed Body" << "\n";
    }

    ~Body() {std::cout << "Destructed Body" << "\n";}


    /*#### Copy/Move ####*/

    Body(const Body &) =default;
    Body & operator=(const Body &) =default;
    Body(Body &&) =default;
    Body & operator=(Body &&) =default;
```

system.hpp:

```
class System {

private:
    std::vector<Body> bodies;

public:

    [[nodiscard]] inline
    std::vector<Body> get_bodies() const {return bodies;}

    inline
    void add_body(Body& body)
    {
        bodies.emplace_back(std::move(body));
    }
};
```

output:

```
----- Test Body -----
Constructed Body
(1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Destructed Body
Destructed Body
Destructed Body
```

I understand that it has to do with `system1.add_body(body1);` and `std::cout << system1.get_bodies()[0].get_pos() << "\n";` but questions are :

- **How can an object be destructed more times than it has been constructed ?**
- **Is this a performance loss (should I be worried about it on a larger scale) ? If so, how can I work my way around it ?**

PS: On a more general manner, I'll be happy to receive advice on my code!

Comment: You didn't instrument copy or move constructors. You simply aren't detecting all the constructions that are occurring.

Comment: Also, write `static_cast<void const*>(this)` to the output, too, so you know which object exactly the output relates to.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, unless your program does something truly perverse (such as explicitly calling a destructor), an object is constructed exactly once and it is destroyed once or not at all.

Comment: *How can an object be destructed more times than it has been constructed ?* -- It can't .  To prove this to you, print the value of `this` in your output, and not just the message "Destructor Body". and "Constructed Body".  You will see some addresses that didn't show up in "Constructed Body", proving that you are not detecting all places where construction is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can an object be destructed more times than it has been constructed ?

It can't.  You are simply not logging every constructor that is being called.

For instance, `bodies.emplace_back(std::move(body))` constructs a new `Body` object using the `Body(Body&&)` move constructor, which you have `default`'ed and are not logging.

And `std::vector<Body> get_bodies() const` returns a *copy* of `bodies`, thus has to make new `Body` objects using the `Body(const Body&)` copy constructor, which you have likewise also `default`'ed and are not logging.

Try the following instead, and you will see a better picture of what is really happening:

```cpp
class Body
{
private:
    Vec3D pos_;
    Vec3D vel_;
    double mass_{ 1 };
    System* system_{ nullptr };

public:

    /*#### Constructors ####*/

    //Body() noexcept = default;
    Body() {
        std::cout << "Default Constructor " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }

    Body(Vec3D pos, Vec3D vel, double mass, System& system)
        : pos_(pos), vel_(vel), mass_(mass), system_(&system)
    {
        ...
        std::cout << "Conversion Constructor " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }

    ~Body() {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }

    /*#### Copy/Move ####*/

    //Body(const Body &) = default;
    Body(const Body &src)
        : pos_(src.pos_), vel_(src.vel_), mass_(src.mass_), system_(src.system_)
    {
        ...
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }

    //Body(Body &&) = default;
    Body(Body &&src)
        : pos_(std::move(src.pos_)), vel_(std::move(src.vel_)), mass_(src.mass_), system_(src.system_)
        ...
        src.mass_ = 0;
        src.system_ = nullptr;
        ...
        std::cout << "Move Constructor " << static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
    }

    //Body& operator=(const Body &) = default;
    Body& operator=(const Body &rhs) {
        if (&rhs != this) {
            pos_ = rhs.pos_;
            vel_ = rhs.vel_;
            mass_ = rhs.mass_;
            system_ = rhs.system_;
        }
        std::cout << "Copy Assignment " << static_cast<const void*>(&rhs) << " -> " static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

    //Body& operator=(Body &&) = default;
    Body& operator=(Body &&rhs) {
        pos_ = std::move(rhs.pos_);
        vel_ = std::move(rhs.vel_);
        mass_ = rhs.mass_; rhs.mass_ = 0;
        system_ = rhs.system_; rhs.system_ = nullptr;
        std::cout << "Move Assignment " << static_cast<void*>(&rhs) << " -> " static_cast<void*>(this) << "\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ...
};
```